# Linear Algebra Derivative Confusion: scalar-to-matrix and matrix-to-scalar functions

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

We have the following variables

- x: scalar
- Y: matrix
- z: scalar

We know that

$$
Y = f(x)
$$

$$
z = g(Y)
$$

We know the form of $f$ but we do not know the form of $g$.

We know the value of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial Y}$.

Since we know the form of $f$, we know the form of $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}$.

Our goal is to determine the value of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. Do we have enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didnt do my research, the wiki page on the chain rule gives the answer to my exact case. I will repeat it here using the notation I used in my question

First of all, I said I wanted to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ but that should be $\frac{dz}{dx}$ because $z$ can be writen as only a function of $x$.

So we wanted to find

$$
\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} g(Y) = \frac{d}{dx} g(f_1(x),...,f_k(x))
$$

We use a single index to write the elements of the matrix function $f$.

From the wiki page

$$
\frac{d}{dx} g(f_1(x),...,f_k(x)) = \sum_{i=1}^k \left( \frac{d}{dx}f_i(x) \right) D_i g(f_1(x),...,f_k(x))
$$

Where $D_i g(f_1(x),...,f_k(x))$ is the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to the $i$th element of $Y$ evaluated at $x$. And we know this value as part of the problem statement.

And we know $\frac{d}{dx}f_i(x)$ because we know the form of $f$.